# Symfony and ReflectionProperty::getDocComment() function

Tags: php, symfony

I am using PHP 5.4.15, MS windows Pro 64bits, apache 2.4 and Symfony 2.2.

Did anyone notice that `ReflectionProperty::getDocComment()` sometimes returns `false` without any reason?

I have a Symfony project and use annotations, and sometimes annotations just don't work. And I found out that Symfony uses `ReflectionProperty::getDocComment()` to grab comments for annotation purposes.

For example:

```php
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 * 
 */
class Order
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction") */
    protected $paymentInstruction;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision = 2) */
    protected $amount;
}
```

When `ReflectionProperty::getDocComment()` processes the `$amount` field, it's not returning the field’s comment but `false`.

If I move that field to the top of the class then `$paymentInstruction` is not been processed.

The only way to get the annotations to work is to move around class fields, in one particular order (permutation), and `ReflectionProperty::getDocComment()` will not return `false`.

Answer (score 2):

My bad.

A PHP doc comment should start with `/**`, but in my class sometimes I use `/*`
that's why `getDocComment()` returns `false`.